# How can I install DistUtilsExtra on Python compiled from sources?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

I'm working on a Raspberry Pi. For some complex reasons I'd rather not get into, I had to remove Python2 and Python3 from the system, and compile Python 3.9.2 from scratch. Works great.

Unfortunately, now, I need Ansible to configure the system, which requires `python3-apt` if you plan to use a task that uses the `apt` module, which I do. `python3-apt` appears to just be [python-apt](https://pypi.org/project/python-apt/), which I can install with `pip`.

Unfortunately, when I try that (`pip install python-apt`), I get this:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'DistUtilsExtra'
```

If my python was installed with `apt`, I could just do:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-distutils-extra
```

But that depends on the python packages from the apt repos, so it will install Python from apt, which I don't want.

`python3-distutils-extra` appears to just be a python package, but I can't seem to find it on pypi. Is there a way to install it without using apt?

Or should I just tell apt to install the package, and ignore installing dependencies?

Comment: This isn't a direct answer to my question, but does solve my problem. Turns out `python3-apt` is not on pypi. It's [here](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/python-apt.git). Installing `libapt-pkg-dev`, and building `python-apt` with `python setup.py build; python setup.py install` solved my problem. I had to use the version from git tag `1.8.4.3` (the same version that apt would have installed), since my libapt-pkg-dev from apt isn't new enough to work with newer versions of `python-apt`, but now, everything works

Answer (score 3):

A possible workaround is to rebuild the wheel from the source code of the apt package

```
apt-get source python3-distutils-extra
cd python-distutils-extra-2.40
python3.9 -m pip install wheel  # You'll need this to run setup.py
python3.9 setup.py bdist_wheel  # Create the wheel
python3.9 -m pip install dist/python_distutils_extra-2.39-py3-none-any.whl  # Install the wheel
```

Comment: `You must put some 'deb-src' URIs in your sources.list.` 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/496549/error-you-must-put-some-source-uris-in-your-sources-list